# How would I go about making a query to both call distinct values from two tables, with another value from one of those tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to make a query that will call unique values from two tables, which in itself is easy. However, I also need a second value to display, but that value is only present in one of the tables. What I mean is this:

Table 1 has computer names. Table 2 has computer names and IP addresses. Many of the computer names are shared between the two, but each list has some unique values that the other doesn't, and some names are all-caps while some aren't, hence the need for DISTINCT. However, when I try to also call in the IP addresses of Table 2 into the query, by giving Table 1 a blank "IPAddresses" field, the resulting table will show something like this

```
Name            IP Address
ComputerOne     
ComputerTwo
ComputerTwo     x.x.x.x
ComputerThree   x.x.x.x
ComputerFour
ComputerFive
ComputerSix
ComputerSix     x.x.x.x
```

How would I go about making a query that would consolidate the entries for computers that exist in both tables, despite that the value for the IP only exists in one?

This is my current query, if that helps

```
SELECT DISTINCT ComputerName, IPAddress
FROM ListA

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT ComputerName, IPAddress
FROM ListB;
```

I'm aware that I'm missing some argument or such, but I'm not sure how to make this work the way I want it to, or if it's possible.

Comment: What would your desired results look like?  Would `computer2` have an `IP` address for both entries.. or would it have just one entry with the ip address, while the `computer1` entry would have no `IP`?

Comment: What I'm trying to get is for computer1 to have nothing in the IP field, but then computer2 will.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your query as it is, then use a 2nd query to summarize it.  Use your query as the source, and group by computer name and select max(IP) as the IP address.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm rather new to SQL queries, first time actually using them for work. What would your solution look like?

Comment: If your query is named Combined_List, the follow-on query would look like "Select Name, Max([IP Address]) as IP from Combined_List Group By Name".  You don't need to do it in SQL, either - use the normal Query design view, select you Union query as the data source and go from there.

Comment: I'll give this approach a shot when I get home, but Gordon got me for now. Thank you

Comment: @ImMetaKnight - this will work with any number of tables in your initial UNION query - just add more "Union select ..." lines

Answer (score 0):

If what you are saying is that when you are querying any of the tables,
you want to filter by pc name that exists in both,
just apply it in the where condition via IN cause filtering on a unioned set.

something like:

```
  create table t_a (name varchar(20) , ip varchar(15));
      create table t_b (name varchar(20) , ip varchar(15));
      insert into t_a select 'pc1' , null;
      insert into t_a select 'pc2' , '127.0.0.1';
      insert into t_b select 'pc1' , '172.18.23.2';
      insert into t_a select 'pc3' , '192.168.0.1';

      select * 
      from <required table> 
      where name in (select name from t_a union select name from t_b)
```

make sense?

Comment: Is this what you meant?

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, but I'm not entirely sure if this is a plausible solution if I'm understanding your method, as the first table has about 200 entries, but the second has well over 6,000. Manually inputting all values would be kinda silly, as by the time I'd finished that task, I could've hand-written the table I'm trying to create. So unless I'm misunderstanding you, I don't know if this is really a feasible solution.

Comment: ignore the inserts, just use the select with the filter, the inserts are just to generate dummy data when you execute the code yourself. got it?

Comment: What I mean is you should union in the filter (I.e. where clause) and project columns from table of your choice

Comment: I see. I'll give this a try when I get home, but for now Gordon got me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want everything from the second table and then the remaining names from the first.  Here is one method:

```
select name, ip
from table2
union all
select name, null
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.name = t1.name);
```

This approach assumes that the two tables have distinct names *within* each table.

Comment: Sorry to bug you, but now, how would I go about doing this same thing again, but for 4 tables?

Comment: @ImMetaKnight . . . You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a single list of computer names with no duplicates using `UNION`, then use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to obtain the matching ip address where there is one:

```
select t3.name, ipaddress
from (
  select name from table1 
  union 
  select name from table2
  ) as t3
  left outer join table2
  on table2.name = t3.name
  ;
```

Note that you may need to use something like `UPPER(name)` if your db is case sensitive.

Here is a working example of the code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f156ee/4